# JSON Apply mapping of a map to object

Tags: json, http, dictionary, go, struct

I'm writing a REST endpoint for an Update operation on a model. The mapping is simply a forwarding of the request's body as `[]byte` to `json.Unmarshal`. However, I'm now trying to filter out the `uuid` property from being changed on said model. So instead of unmarshaling to the model I am now doing it to a `map[string]interface{}` and then running `delete(m, "uuid")`.

At this point I have a map of the data, but how can I feed it into the `json` to map it as it usually would when calling `Unmarshal` or `Decode`? Is there a better option than marshaling for a `[]byte` result and then unmarshal onto the model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may mark the UUID field of your object (struct) with `json:"-"` so it will be excluded from the marshaling / unmarshaling process, e.g.:

```
type User struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    UUID string `json:"-"`
}
```

If you do need to marshal / unmarshal the UUID field too at other places of your app, then the simplest solution would be to store the UUID field before unmarshaling, then restore it after the marshaling, e.g.:

```
u := getUser() // acquire your object

uuid := u.UUID // save field

err := json.Unmarshal(data, &u)
// handle error

u.UUID = uuid // restore field
```

Wrap it in a utility function, so you can reuse it:

```
func decodeUser(u *User, data []byte) error {
    uuid := u.UUID // save field
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &u); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    u.UUID = uuid // restore field
    return nil
}
```

Note that there are 3rd party libs for mapping maps to struts values (e.g. [`github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure`](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure)), but unmarshaling into a map first, then mapping that into a struct is significantly slower than to unmarshaling into the struct value and storing / restoring a single field.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I have tried this and it does not work. Worth noting my UUID field is defined
```
UUID uuid.UUID `json:"uuid,-"`
```

Comment: @SupaHam You must use `json:"-"`, providing a name too will not work.

Comment: Really? Surely that's a design flaw?

Comment: @SupaHam Why? `-` is not an "option", it's a special name value.

Comment: Oh of course. My bad. Well I will need it for marshalling actually. I'll have to temporarily store the old uuid. Although, it might be better finding a more feature-ful library instead.

Comment: @SupaHam All it takes is to wrap that few lines in a `decodeUser()` utility function, and you can reuse it...

Comment: Correct. However, generally wanting to process JSON in other forms will only prove difficult. One can tell this library wasn't designed for this level of processing as everything only revolves around a `[]byte`

Comment: @SupaHam There is a 3rd party lib (see edited answer) for exactly what you asked for, but using that would be slower and unnecessary in the case you mentioned.

Comment: "as everything only revolves around a `[]byte`" that's what JSON is. The only other thing you could call it is a `string`, but under the hood, a `string` is also a `[]byte`. So it's not clear how this is a shortcoming or flaw of `encoding/json`.